# comic miniseries: Teenagers show superpowers, conscripted into military

Tags: story-identification, comics, powers

About 25 years ago I found issue 1 of this miniseries in a comic shop. It was secondhand then, so probably a few years older.

Several teenagers in USA begin to exhibit random super powers. I remember that one could create at will a network of interlocking pipes, to make a ladder, or cage, or frame. Another had a hubcap which he could throw and do tricks like Captain America's shield. I don't remember any of the others.

They receive draft notices. The father of one of them says it's like Vietnam again. The father had been drafted, and doesn't want his son going through the same thing.

The President holds a press conference to explain the draft. Somebody tries to shoot him, or bomb him, or something,  but he survives an attack that should have killed him. A reporter says "Mr President, do YOU have a super power?"  The President says "Well ... "

End of first issue.  That's all I saw. It seemed interesting, and I'd like to see if I can find the whole thing, but I don't remember what it was called.

Comment: Hubcaps, you say? https://comicvine.gamespot.com/metallurgist/4005-29210/

Comment: Thank you, Valorum, that's it. Specifically, its a one shot called The Draft, which is shown on the Comics tag. Enter that as an Answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's [*The Draft*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Draft_(comics)), a one-shot comic from Marvel's New Universe line.

Two of the characters were:

> - Christopher Barrett (Metallurgist): Has a 1949 Chevy hubcap that he can apparently control with his mind. He's able to use it to fly.
>   Barrett turns 18 the day before the United States Congress approves
>   the draft.
> - Garth (Gridlock): Able to create tubes of force in geometric forms. Garth is 34 years old, and married with a daughter, but enlists out of
>   a desire to take charge of his life.

As mentioned, it was a one-shot, so there was no second issue. But it was the second in a trilogy—the others being *The Pitt* one-shot and 4-issue *The War*—that drastically changed the New Universe.

Comment: I am particularly amused by the idea that they specifically want to draft people with superpowers, but forgot to include women. A bit of an oversight there, cutting your superhuman soldier selection in half.